# A question regarding the definition of differentiable.

Tags: limits, derivatives, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a differentiable function, then it holds that
$$f(y)=f(x)+f'(x)(y-x)+o(|y-x|).$$
Here a function $g(x)=o(|x-y|)$ if 
$$\lim_{x\to y}\frac{|g(x)|}{|x-y|}=0.$$
If we let $\gamma(y)=f(x+y)-f(x)-f'(x)y$, then we see that
\begin{align}
\gamma(y_1)-\gamma(y_2)&=(f(x+y_1)-f(x)-f'(x)y_1)-(f(x+y_2)-f(x)-f'(x)y_2)\\
&=f(x+y_1)-f(x+y_2)-f'(x)(y_1-y_2)\\
&=f(x+y_1)-f(x+y_2)-f'(x)([x+y_1]-[x+y_2])\\
&=o(|[x+y_1]-[x+y_2]|)\\
&=o(|y_1-y_2|).
\end{align}
This means that $\lim_{y_1\to y_2}\frac{|\gamma(y_1)-\gamma(y_2)|}{|y_1-y_2|}=0.$

Now consider the case that $f(x)=x^2$, then we see that 
$$f(x+y)=x^2+2xy+y^2,$$
and thus $$\gamma(y)=y^2,$$
which means that
$$0=\lim_{y_1\to y_2}\frac{|\gamma(y_1)-\gamma(y_2)|}{|y_1-y_2|}=\lim_{y_1\to y_2}\frac{|(y_1+y_2)||(y_1-y_2)|}{|y_1-y_2|}=2y_2.$$
The theory given now tells us that the limit on the left hand side goes to zero, but the right hand limit seems to be different?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have realised the inconsistency here (and thus I am happy to remove this post if need be, since it was due to my own oversight). Where we have
$$\gamma(y_1)-\gamma(y_2)=f(x+y_1)-f(x+y_2)-f'(x)([x+y_1]-[x+y_2]),$$
we cannot apply the given theory directly, since we are evaluating the derivative at $f'(x)$, rather than say $f'(x+y_2)$, which would be necessary to make the deduction.